# How to rename a part of path in a fileset

Tags: ant

i have a fileset and i want to rename a part of the pathes:

For example:

```
From
c:\projects\a\dir\subdir\file1.txt
To
c:\projects\b\dir2\subdir\file1.txt
```

In this case i want to rename "a\dir" to "b\dir2".

Why do I need this? I have two project directories: a and b. I want to delete all files in b that exist in a (with ant).
Example2 with files:

```
c:\projects\a\dir\file1.txt
c:\projects\a\dir\subdir\file2.txt

c:\projects\b\dir\file1.txt
c:\projects\b\dir\subdir\file2.txt
c:\projects\b\dir\file3.txt
```

In this case I want delete file1.txt and subdir/file2.txt from project b (because only this two exist in project a).

Getting a fileset is easy:

```
<path id="filesInProjectA">
    <fileset dir="c:\projects\a" includes="**/*.*" />
</path>
```

I tried to use `<pathconvert.../>` but it did not work for me...

Thanks:
Andras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<pathconvert property="filePaths" refid="filesInProjectA" pathsep=";">
    <map from="c:\projects\a\dir\" to="c:\projects\a\dir2\" />
</pathconvert>
```

This should work.  This will put in property filePaths all the converted paths separated by ';'.  While it's not important what symbol separates the paths, it is important to know what symbol it is, which is why it should be specified.

Afterwards you can use this to perform an operation on each converted path:

```
<foreach list="${filePaths}" delimiter=";" target="target-for-each-path" param="path" />
```

Comment: Hi Neil! This works fine. However not so beauty. Is there a way that the result is also a fileset? Thanks: Andras

Comment: At last i used this version (at least calls no other target, but it is  still not fileset conversion...):

`<for  list="${filePaths}" delimiter=";"  param="path" parallel="true" threadCount="5">
    <sequential>
        <delete file="@{path}" failonerror="no"/>
    </sequential>
</for>`

Comment: @Andras, unfortunately not that I know of.  There might be a way, but the only way I've managed to do this is this way.